# How to combine comma-separated string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My scenario is simple:

1. Split a file into 3 pieces(e.g, test.txt -> 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt)
2. Do bit operation to create parity file(p.txt)
3. If one file(2.txt) is missing, restore through the remaining files(0.txt, 1.txt, p.txt)

I've done with above 3 steps, but I have a small problem.

[image] is original contents of 2.txt and 
[image] is restored.

As you can see, the restored contents are comma-separated.

I just wonder how I can get contents same as original file.

Below is my code:

```
    testRestore() {
    // test input : 2 split files and 1 parity file

    this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.path, '0_test.txt').then(arraybuffer => {
        var temp = [];
        temp[0] = arraybuffer;
        alert(this.ab2str(temp[0]));
        this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.path, '1_test.txt').then(arraybuffer => {
            temp[1] = arraybuffer;
            alert(this.ab2str(temp[1]));
            this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.path, '3_test.txt').then(arraybuffer => {
                temp[2] = arraybuffer;
                alert(this.ab2str(temp[2]));

                this.file.writeFile(this.path, 'restored_file.txt', this.genParity(temp));
            });
        });
    });
}

// Input : string object array
// Output : 1 parity buffer
genParity(temparr) {
    alert('here, temparr = ' + temparr);

    var parityBuf;

    for (let k = 0; k < temparr.length - 1; k++) {
        parityBuf = this.doParity(this.ab2str(temparr[k]), this.ab2str(temparr[k + 1]));
    }

    alert('parityBuf = ' + parityBuf);
    return parityBuf;
}

doParity(str1, str2) {
    //String to Array of char codes
    let transform = (n) => n.split("").map(v => v.charCodeAt(0));
    let a = transform(str1);
    let b = transform(str2);
    let asc = a.map((v, i) => String.fromCharCode(v ^ b[i]));
    return asc;
}
```

Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks.

※ This code is TypeScript and I used a native plugin of Ionic F/W(`readAsArrayBuffer(path, name, contents)`), but I'm sure If you're familiar with JavaScript, there're no problems to understand and fix the issue.

Comment: Since you end up with an array of characters, is it not just simple enough to do a join before writing to the file? So I guess `this.genParity(temp).join()`?

I may be thinking too simple though.

Comment: `this.genParity(temp).join()` removed " " on the contents, but comma still remained. As the answer below, `this.genParity(temp).join('')` gave the result I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` function:

```
yourArray.join('');
```